# Why Gentoo detects no network devices?

Tags: linux, networking, kernel, drivers, gentoo

I've faced the problem installing Gentoo: after the installation is seems to be completed and LiveCD is extracted, network becomes unreachable:

`gentoo~ # ping 8.8.8.8`

`connect: Network is unreachable`

`ifconfig` shows only loopback device `lo` and no actual network devices (there should be also ethernet `enp3s0` and wireless `wlp4s0` interfaces).

Here's what I see using `lspci`:

`gentoo~ # lspci | grep Eth`

`03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8131 Gigabit Ethernet (rev c0)`

I thought that probably Kernel was compiled without the driver for this device. To check that out I should find the driver's name (used http://kmuto.jp/)

`gentoo~ # lspci -n`

...

`03:00.0 0200: 1969:1063 (rev c0)`

...

So the name is `atl1c`, which relates to `Atheris L1C Gigabit Ethernet`, support of which was included to the Kernel before compilation.

Comment: Check `lspci -k` and the output lines `Kernel drivers in use ` and `Kernel modules`. Maybe you need to load the drivers module `modprobe atl1c` or similar.

Comment: Does `ifconfig -a` show the interfaces? If it doesn't, that's a driver problem. If it does, then you just need to do the network configuration (e.g. activate DHCP or set a static IP address and gateway).

Comment: `ip link show` helps too.

Comment: @ikrabbe `lspci` shows nothing Kernel related below the device info. `ip link show` shows no info on the enp3s0 interface.

Comment: @Gilles Nope, I can't see `enp3s0` in `ifconfig -a` output.

Comment: @hdf: That's a good hint, that your kernel does not know about the atl1c module or driver.

Comment: @ikrabbe but in Kernel's Ethernet driver support I see `<*>    Atheros L1C Gigabit Ethernet support`. Doesn't that mean that Kernel was compiled including the driver?

Comment: Do you run that kernel? lspci -k asks the running kernel about the module names.

Comment: @ikrabbe good question. I was sure I do run it.

Comment: Would you please post the output of `dmesg | grep renamed` along with `ifconfig -a`?

Comment: @eyoung100 It looks like I've found the solution. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Gentoo/Linux LiveCD Ethernet won't connect: troubleshooting steps:**

1. Re-Confirm that you have the latest .iso or Bootable USB image from the official boot media website.  Motherboard/Ethernet Manufacturers like Intel introduce breaking updates and Linux developers have to fix it with software updates.
2. Re-Confirm that your internet and wired Cat5 cable is working correctly by plugging the Cat5 into another computer and connecting.  If that just works, then internet and the Cat5 cable is good.  Otherwise replace those.
3. Re-Confirm that there aren't any superfluous or bugged devices or set top boxes between your computer and the ISP service provider, such as 5 port hubs, switches, routers (bridge mode or otherwise) or other relay devices.  By eliminating these network hops, you confirm that the liveCD can "see through" them.  If that fixes, flash-update hub/switch/router's hardware.
4. Re-Confirm that your computer has the BIOS/CMOS or motherboard settings enabled for Ethernet card, your computer might have support for multiple Ethernet cards, or you're simply plugging into the non-default one.  Press F2/F12/Del after reboot and find any settings in regards to Ethernet, or network stack, enable/disable legacy IPv4 and IPv6 settings.
5. Re-Confirm that your computer isn't getting hung up negotiating between two or more Ethernet cards.  If you can remove a removable Ethernet card, that may isolate errors.  Your Ethernet card might be knockoff 3rd party, use modprobe to load the ethernet driver your manufacturer endorses.
6. Now the integrity of your Ethernet hardware or boot media reader is suspect.  Try a different LiveCD or different Boot USB, like Ubuntu, Arch, SystemRescueCD or other.  Burn that to CD or Boot USB.  If that one just works, it proves at least your Ethernet card hardware hasn't given up the ghost.
7. If Ethernet still doesn't autoconnect from any of these boot mediums.  The Hardware is suspect.  Remove any unnecessary PCI cards that can be removed, remove unnecessary Memory.
8. If god forbid none of that works, perhaps Linux is getting behind the 8 ball, try installing a different kind of operating system.
9. If none of that works, your hardware has given up the ghost.

https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64/Installation/Networking

What ultimately remedied it for me was a recompile of the kernel. I loaded the driver but not actually installed it.

The solution is:

`gentoo~ # cd /usr/src/linux`

`gentoo linux # make modules_install`

`gentoo linux # cp arch/x86/boot/bzImage /boot/kernel-genkernel-x86_64-4.0.5-gentoo`

`gentoo linux # reboot`